# Internet speeduys

Tags: wireless, internet, browser, websites, wifi-hardware-switch

we are using 4 ubuntu machines with 20 Mbps internet speed were the browsing speed is very low we used to wait for a long time to buffer a video.Is there any solution for this need very much needed.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Did you test your network using another OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 & 15.10 & 16.04Lts we are running few different on all individual machines.